# php Exact string match with underscores

Tags: php, regex, string-matching

I am trying to get an exact match on a string containing a certain part of text.
For example the string is : `CAR_NW_BMW_X3_21_01_IMPORT_X_PREMIUM`

The string changes but only the last part; `IMPORT_X_PREMIUM` so it could be `IMPORT_Y_PREMIUM`
Based on that i would like to check if the that part exists in the full string.

I tried with preg_match but this doesn't work, I am not an expert in regex so I probably made a mistake.

```
$str = "CAR_NW_BMW_X3_21_01_IMPORT_X_PREMIUM"
preg_match("~\bIMPORT_X_PREMIUM\b~",$str)
```

How could this be achieved?

Comment: You can use an end of subject match (i.e. $) so `preg_match("/IMPORT_X_PREMIUM$/~",$str)` should do what you want.

Comment: @Sherif this gives `preg_match(): Unknown modifier '~'`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use

```php
preg_match("~(?<![^\W_])IMPORT_X_PREMIUM(?![^\W_])~",$str)
```

See [regex proof](https://regex101.com/r/Zmg8n1/1).

`(?<![^\W_])...(?![^\W_])` are word boundaries that exclude `_`.

Also consider:

```php
preg_match("~(?<=\b|_)IMPORT_X_PREMIUM(?=_|\b)~",$str)
```

See [another regex proof](https://regex101.com/r/Zmg8n1/2). Meaning, either word boundaries, or underscores.

**EXPLANATION**

```php
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  (?<!                     look behind to see if there is not:
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    [^\W_]                   any character except: non-word
                             characters (all but a-z, A-Z, 0-9, _),
                             '_'
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  )                        end of look-behind
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  IMPORT_X_PREMIUM         'IMPORT_X_PREMIUM'
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  (?!                      look ahead to see if there is not:
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    [^\W_]                   any character except: non-word
                             characters (all but a-z, A-Z, 0-9, _),
                             '_'
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  )                        end of look-ahead
```